# Margens bugadas no CSS

Tags: css, imagem, margens

Estou tentando colocar uma borda numa imagem, mas o resultado é que a margem se estende por toda horizontal da página, como mostra no print.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é que a margem fique ao redor da imagem e de sua legenda...

No HTML:

```
<figure class = 'foto-legenda'>
    <img src = '_imagens/glass-quadro-homem-mulher.jpg'>
    <figcaption>
        <h3>Google Glass</h3>
        <p>Uma nova maneira de ver o mundo.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

No CSS:

```
figure.foto-legenda {
    border: 8px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
}
```

O professor também instruiu a incluir o seguinte trecho, a fim de evitar que a margem se "desalinhe" à imagem ao redimensionar a janela do navegador:

```
figure.foto-legenda img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Ao fazer isso, aparentemente a borda se encaixa direitinho, mas a imagem fica gigantesca...

P. S.: Eu já tentei remover os textos da legenda, mas o resultado foi o mesmo.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi bem a pergunta, o que faltou aí foi vc declarar um tamanho máximo para o `conteiner`, ou seja, o lugar que os outros elementos irão se encaixar, que no caso aí é a tag **figure**. No caso do meu exemplo, a imagem que coloquei tem a largura (width) de `536px`:

```css
figure.foto-legenda {
  max-width: 536px;         /* seta o tamanho fixo */
  border: 8px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
}

figure.foto-legenda img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foto-legenda">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/257/536/354.jpg?hmac=nm-DRQwYb7mx97h32hITnpzDptvXok_UJCT3CY-LxJY">
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Google Glass</h3>
    <p>Uma nova maneira de ver o mundo.</p>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: A sua solução deu certo, muito obrigado; só fico curioso pelo motivo de que o professor não teve que fazer isso... Será que pode ser porque a aula é de 2013 e de lá pra cá mudou o funcionamento dessas propriedades ou algo assim?

Comment: Bernardo, não sei dizer exatamente pois teria que ver os código, mas, tem uma grande possibilidade de este ser o motivo. Se não me engano o **HTML5** só foi lançado em 2014 oficialmente, acho eu, então provavelmente até o próprio HTML do curso aí seja uma versão inferior aos dos browsers atuais. Por isso, talvez, muitas das coisas que o professor mostra como fazer difere da maneira atual. A dica é sempre procurar fazer cursos mais atuais possíveis, pois, as tecnologias mudam muito rápido e evoluem muito de uma versão para outra!